# Android - How to handler timeout

Tags: android, crash, timeout

I have a problem with request POST/GET in Android.
I am trying to handle the error:

Caused by: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

To prevent the crash on my application, I added a timeout of  40 seconds.  That works but sometimes 40 seconds is not enough to avoid the error.

I tried to add the "try and catch" but it seems that the error isn't occurring inside here:

```
try {
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE,
                    Backend2.cookieStore);
            response = HttpManager.execute(request, localContext);
            if (response.getEntity() != null) {
                final String r = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                return r;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

I am looking for a solution but when I read on stackoverflow and on google, I see only posts like "increase your timeout, add a try, etc.."

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell just looking at your catch statement, but maybe you are getting a different error than a SocketTimeoutException? Try to catch an Exception instead to confirm that.

Comment: I updated the post with the full try and catch, Should I add just Exception ?

Comment: As you said before, sometimes you catch a SocketTimeoutException and sometimes you don't, so I think that you're probably getting a different error. Try to catch an Exception instead, unless you have different treatments for each type of exception.